# Given a type define a union of functions with parameters keys of the type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following types and I have to define `formatter` with a union type parameter.

```
declare type TableHeadCell<T> = {
    key: keyof T;
    label: string;
    formatter?: (cell: T[keyof T], row?: T) => string;
};

declare type Product = {
    article: string;
    quantity: number
};

const myTHeadCell: TableHeadCell<Product> = {
   key: 'article',
   label: 'Article',
   formatter(cell: string | number, row: Product): string { /* ... */ }
}
```

What I need instead is a union function type which will allow me to define the function with either type of parameters. It would be best if it's possible to narrow to the type of `key`.

```
const myTHeadCell: TableHeadCell<Product> = {
   key: 'article',
   label: 'Article',
   formatter(cell: string, row: Product): string { /* ... */ }
}

// or

const myTHeadCell: TableHeadCell<Product> = {
   key: 'quantity',
   label: 'Article',
   formatter(cell: number, row: Product): string { /* ... */ }
};
```

Comment: AFAICT you can't have a union type for functions, but you can for interfaces, so you could have a `HeaderFormatter` and `CellFormatter`, both with `format` methods with different signatures. Then type guards could help you make it ergonomic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to proceed here is for `TableHeadCell<T>` to be a [union](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) type with one member for each `K` in `keyof T`.  One way to achieve that is to make a mapped type where each property corresponds to each `K`, and then get a union of those properties:

```
type TableHeadCell<T> = { [K in keyof T]: {
  key: K;
  label: string;
  formatter?: (cell: T[K], row?: T) => string;
} }[keyof T];
```

Now you can write the following with no error:

```
const myTHeadCell1: TableHeadCell<Product> = {
  key: 'article',
  label: 'Article',
  formatter(cell: string, row?: Product): string { return "" }
}

const myTHeadCell2: TableHeadCell<Product> = {
  key: 'quantity',
  label: 'Article',
  formatter(cell: number, row?: Product): string { return "" }
};
```

The compiler will even remember that `myTHeadCell1.formatter()` takes a `string` parameter, while `myTHeadCell2.formatter()` takes a `number` because [control flow type analysis](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8010) will temporarily narrow the type of a union-typed value based upon assignment:

```
if (myTHeadCell1.formatter) {
  myTHeadCell1.formatter(""); // okay
  myTHeadCell1.formatter(123); // error
}
if (myTHeadCell2.formatter) {
  myTHeadCell2.formatter(""); // error
  myTHeadCell2.formatter(123); // okay
}
```

Please note that I changed the formatter implementations so that `row` was optional.  That's necessary to match the definition of `TableHeadCell<T>`.  If you want the `row` parameter to be required in the implementation, it needs to be required in the annotated type, because you should be allowed to call a `TableHeadCell<T>.formatter!()` with one argument according to the definition.  (Make sure you understand the distinction between a function type with optional parameters and a function implementation which ignores extra parameters, as described [in the TypeScript FAQ](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters)).

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgIwDYQBITgEwMISUgHhgD4oBeKAbygG0BpKASwDsoBrCEAewDNYBdAFxUAUFHadhdANxioSRHmEBnYACcWAc1nieXNQFs4wYBDUB+YQAoAxniTCY9fgBooargHdLsAJTlSVQ1mbREAXygwmg5uPhh+WRFQSCgABQ9MAFcbYHJRcTg1YEYbFBV1LR0oAEdMuGZi0GFmTIMEM3DEmy5mVSgDEBh0LFx8AEZHRBRhnHsCdK4snNIKSjkY4QByQuLSiE2XOQV2hyhNgEEikpQDuT1DY1M1W3ty4M03D29hBaXgXzeWio7ggwEyalYACJIZFwiIRN1erkBkMMLN8AAmSbINBo0aEX7ZYArfISEBbWr1RogW7iY5KM6XXY3Q66fRGExmF74ZqtdpqT5eHyEnIAqBBIHUNSg8FQmFhTrwxh8Kwomb4sYAOnuHKe-jW4jVePsWp1jy50N80igAHobVAuGw4CA5EaRibtezzc8xhiAMxW232sweNRw5VQVWDdX2DGeh6ctT613R42Y+O6i2QwN2qAh-Qp1Hu9NmxNWX0B625x3OqDhIA)

Comment: An amazing answer! Thanks for the clarification about ignored parameters, too.